# OBS Studio : Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" - Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, wayland, qt, obs-studio

I encountered this problem after re-installing `Arch Linux`, in the previous version of my arch system was working properly, but it is not working now, here is the terminal log output:

```bash
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, xcb, vkkhrdisplay, minimalegl, vnc, linuxfb, minimal, offscreen.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: probably a missing or not-update dependency; is your system up-to-date?

Comment: yes my system is up-to-date, I update it regularly.

Comment: Running kde-plasma DE ?

Comment: I'm using Gnome

Comment: install the package `qt6-wayland`; does this solve the issue?

Comment: @mattia.b89 nope, it did not

Comment: maybe this bug report https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/72972 can help you; if not, open a new one!